# Receive and save attachments from emails using Database Mail

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I know you used to be able to do this using the stored procedure 'sp_processmail' using SQL Mail but is there a way to do this now?

I am interested in solutions for SQL Server 2012 and 2014.

Comment: Yes, you can use sp_send_dbmail to send attachments. But you need to configure DB mail before doing that. http://www.idevelopment.info/data/SQLServer/DBA_tips/Database_Administration/DBA_22.shtml should help in configuring DB mail.